# How to totcount 2 different values in one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get totcount value of two different values in one mysql query. My current sql query is as follow :-

```
$sql="SELECT `state`, `district`, `postoffice`, count(`district`) as totcount FROM `tbl_pincodes` WHERE `state`='$state' group by `district`";
```

In the above query, I'm getting the total number of districts of the state as a result. I'd like to get total number of postoffices available in the state as well using single query. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to remove `group by district`. You can count distinct districts, postoffices.   `SELECT `state`, `district`, `postoffice`, count(`Distinct district`), COUNT(DISTINCT postoffices).... `

Comment: COUNT will return the no of rows. u can use like `SUM(postoffice) as postofficeTotal, SUM(district) as districtTotal ` or u can get the count using php

Comment: Can you share your data model and maybe modify the question to be about SQL only? The PHP really is not needed to explain your problem.

Comment: @devpro, count(`district`) is returning the number of districts available in the state by using $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);, however, I want to fetch total total of districts and post offices separately using single query.

Comment: @MichielB Here is little more code that I'm using :-
`$sql="SELECT `state`, `district`, `postoffice`, count(`district`) as totcount FROM `tbl_pincodes` WHERE `state`='$state' group by `district`";`
`$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);`
`$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);`

The above code is rendering the total number of districts available in the state by using echo rowcount in php.

Comment: Let us know the table structure.under postoffice field you have stored no. of post office or only postoffice name/location?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Under PostOffice column, I've only stored the postoffice names, for other values of the tables are :_

ID, state, district, postoffice, pincode, region, circle, taluk, phone, iso

So what I exactly need is :- if state A has 15 districts and has 415 postoffices, I'd like to fetch both the count values separately using same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uery in the question does not return the number of districts per state because it groups by on the district field.

If you need the number of districts and post offices in a state, then group by on state and count the **distinct** values in post office and district fields:

```
SELECT `state`,
       count(distinct `district`) as cnt_district,
       count(distinct `postoffice`) as cnt_postoffice
FROM `tbl_pincodes`
WHERE `state`='$state' group by `state`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT district, postoffice, COUNT(*) 
FROM tbl_pincodes GROUP BY district, postoffice
```

Use Group By for both column will return the no of records against both columns.

Comment: and how will I echo the different values?

Comment: @VikasKukreja: this is another question, for this u must need to learn mysqli_* or PDO

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use "WITH ROLLUP" at the end of the GROUP BY

```
SELECT `state`, `district`, count(*) as count 
FROM `tbl_pincodes` 
WHERE `state` = 1 
GROUP BY `district` WITH ROLLUP
```

[MySQL Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvZNq.png)

This will give you an extra row at the bottom of the query withe the district as null and the count from above two districts summed together. If you cannot use the district NULL, you can use a coalesce to turn the NULL value into something more useful.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

try this :

SELECT district, postoffice, COUNT(*) as count
FROM tbl_pincodes GROUP BY district, postoffice

you will get extra column named `count` .